# Buffer I/O error, lost sync page write and blk_update_request I/O error on hibernate

Tags: hibernate

This question is similar to some other Qs with the same errors, but for one main difference:

When I try to put Ubuntu into hibernate I get a number of I/O related errors;

```
bkl_update_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector xxxxxxxxx (this is repeated for a few sectors)
Buffer I/O error on device sde6, logical block xxxxxxxxx
Aborting jounal on device sde6-8
Buffer I/O error on device sde6, logical block xxxxxxxxx, lost sync page write
```

screenshot of error:
[image: screenshot of error]

In other posts which show simular errors the response is always that "your harddrive is failing".  However I've installed gsmartcontrol and run both short and extended tests and they report that there are no errors (unless I'm missing/misreading something).

extract from log:

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE          UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       14756
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       1699
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   096   096   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       43
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   069   054   000    Old_age   Always       -       31
195 ECC_Error_Rate          0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 CRC_Error_Count         0x003e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
235 POR_Recovery_Count      0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       468
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       28759429511

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged
```

Full log here - http://pastie.org/10974743

I assumed (probablly incorrectly, as my swap is on sde5 and the errors seem to reference sde6), that maybe the problem was with the swap partition. So I created a swap file on another disk, set that up in my fstab and disabled my current swap partition. But I got the same errors as before.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the kernel upgraded to 4.8.1-040801-generic (not sure if that's significant, but it's one of the main changes I've made since install).
I have less swap space than I have ram, but in the past that has never been a problem hibernating so long as the swap space was greater than the amount of ram being used. I've got 32GB of RAM, 16GB of swap space.

It seems to me that the problem is not due to the disk as the smart data reports no errors. This error only occurs while attempting to hibernate (which is something I really need). So I'm guessing that this is due to something else. How can I debug this further? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: The `do_irq` errors indicate a BIOS bug, which is affecting your CPU. This might result in memory buffer overflow errors. You should get a BIOS-update. When resolving this bug, the newer kernel should also work. I had a similar case where Firefox was allocating memory forever (32GB RAM + 32GB SWAP).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this issue is to do with the upgraded Kernel.  With the Kernel at version 4.4 hibernation works just fine, but if I upgrade to one of the newer ones then I get the I/O errors shown above.  Downgrading back to 4.4 resolves the issue.